# What does it mean for an integer $n$ to have $k$ expressions as $x^2 + y^2$?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

I need to write a Maple procedure to find the first integer $n$ with $k$ representations as 
$x^2 + y^2 = n$. I do not really understand what this statement means

Comment: Sometimes an integer can be written as a sum of two squares. Sometimes it can be written as a sum of two squares in multiple ways. You are asked to write a program that finds the first positive integer $n$ which can be written as a sum of two squares in $k$ different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You’re to write a procedure that, when given $k$, finds the smallest integer $n$ that can be written as the sum of two square in $k$ different ways. For $k=2$, this number is $50$: $50=5^2+5^2=7^2+1^2$. The next such number is $65=7^2+4^2=8^2+1^2$, but you don’t want it: it’s not the smallest such number.

Answer (score 0):

A related concept to what you are being asked to write a program for is that of Taxicab Numbers.

The $n^{th}$ taxi cab number, labled as $\text{Ta}(n)$ is the smallest number that can be expressed in $n$ different ways as a sum of two positive cubes.  I.e. the first integer $k$ to have $n$ representations as $x^3+y^3=k$.

The first four taxicab numbers are as follows:

$\begin{matrix}
Ta(1) = & 2  & =1^3+1^3\\
Ta(2) = & 1729  & =1^3 + 12^3\\
& & = 9^3 + 10^3\\
Ta(3) = & 87539319 & =167^3+436^3\\
 & & =228^3 + 423^3\\
 & & =255^3 + 414^3\\
Ta(4) = & 6963472309248 & =2421^3 + 19083^3\\
& & = 5436^3 + 18948^3\\
& & = 10200^3 + 18072^3\\
& & =13322^3 + 16630^3
\end{matrix}$

In much the same way, you are being asked to write a program which finds the smallest number which can be written in $k$ different ways as a sum of squares.  (note, we do not consider $9^3+10^3$ different than $10^3 + 9^3$.  As such, you may assume without loss of generality that $x\leq y$ in your program to avoid accidentally counting the "same" situation more than once).